# Access nested cell array

Tags: matlab, nested, cell-array

I have a cell array of size 1x84, where the elements are 1x1 or 1x2 cells.

I woluld like to get a cell array of size 1x84 by taking the first element from the nested cells

```
CellList = <1x84 cell>

CellList  = <1x1 cell>  <1x1 cell>  <1x1 cell>  <1x2 cell>  <1x1 cell> ... <1x2 cell>
```

The subelements are also cells

---

I tried using this code:

```
CellList = cellfun(@(x)x{1,:}{1,:},CellList, 'UniformOutput',0);
```

But I faced the following error:

```
error : Cell contents reference from a non-cell array object.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`cellfun` accesses each element of the cell you give it, so you are taking an element `x`, trying to access its first element, and the first element of that which doesn't exist.

You want to use

```
CellList2 = cellfun(@(x)x{1}, CellList, 'uniformoutput', false)
```

---

Edit:

You claim you're still getting an error, in which case your problem is not reproducible. Here is some setup code:

```
% define a 1x84 cell array
c = cell(1,84);
% Make each element a 1x2 or 1x1 cell array 
for n = 1:84; c{n} = cell(1,randi([1,2],1)); end;
% Output is as you've described and shown
>> c = <1x84 cell>
     = <1x2 cell> <1x1 cell> <1x1 cell> ... <1x2 cell>
```

Now use my above code, and it works fine.

```
d = cellfun(@(x)x{1},c,'uniformoutput',false);
d = <1x84 cell>
  = [] [] [] [] ... []   % All empty elements as we initialised empty cells
```

Comment: error : Cell contents reference from a non-cell array object.
still the same error

Comment: Then please post example code (in a question edit) which *generates* an equivalent cell array to use for testing... for example are the sub-elements actually cells or just normal matrices?

Comment: for i = 1:84
    c{i} = c{i}(1);
    end

Above code has solved my issue in very short method. Sorry, if my question confused.

I feel what u have explained is very complex in my requirement.

Comment: What is that supposed to mean?